# Write to file in Assembly

Tags: assembly, file-io, buffer, dos, emu8086

I have a task to print a buffer and some other text into a file and when I use this code I get a wrong answer. Outputing a buffer is OK, it prints perfectly, but when I try to print text, declared in data, non-senses start happening. For example, when I try to print "Hello (letters )", it gives me this "Hello (9 spaces)(letters$)$". When I write 3 different procedures for each string, it prints correctly. Maybe you can help me find the problem, guys?

```
model small

BufSize EQU 60

.stack 100h
.data
    rez db "rez.txt", 
    Buf db BufSize dup (?)
    handle  dw ?
    Letters db 0
    brackets1 db " (letters$"
    brackets2 db ")$"
.code
start:
    MOV ax, @data
    MOV ds, ax

    MOV ah, 3Ch
    MOV cx, 0
    MOV dx, offset rez
    INT 21h              ;results file is created and opened
    MOV handle, ax

    MOV cx, 5            ;5 bytes ("Hello")
    ADD cx,10            ;10 bytes from "(letters " and ")"
    MOV bx, handle
    CALL    Write

    MOV ah, 3Eh
    MOV bx, handle
    INT 21h              ;close file

    MOV ah, 4Ch
    MOV al, 0
    INT 21h 

PROC Write
    PUSH    dx

    MOV ah, 40h
    MOV dx, offset Buf
    INT 21h          ;Write to file

    MOV ah,40h
    MOV dx,offset brackets1
    INT 21h 

    MOV ah,40h
    MOV dx,offset brackets2
    INT 21h

    POP dx
    RET
RasykBuf ENDP

END start
```

Comment: `MOV cx, ax ;ax - 5 bytes ("Hello")` what is that supposed to do? You realize `ax` contains the file handle, right? Adding `10` to that makes no sense? Also, the `brackets1/2` in `Write` don't specify a length. Furthermore, `Buf` is uninitialized, not sure why you think that would print `Hello`.

Comment: Its not my whole code, I'm reading from file and buff is fine. Just with that print... I've edited it. So you say I shouldn't add anything to amount of bytes that have to be printed?

Comment: Your `Write` is still broken as I said, and if this is not the code you are actually using that's just misleading and wasting our time. See [mcve] and [no mcve](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: It would take too long to translate it from my language. The main thing is about the Write anyways, so I can't find whats wrong in it. What means that they don't specify a length. I'm new to assembly.

Comment: Assembly or other language, you have 3 `write()` (I mean the INT21/40) calls in there, each needs its own pointer and length. You only change pointers but use the same length (apparently the total bytes to write every time). That doesn't sound right, but hard to tell... We are terribly sorry if it's inconvenient for you to make a [mcve], but we are trying to help you so you should be a little more forthcoming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some omitted instruction and new comments; there was one compiling error that I've corrected: `RasycBuf ENDP` (isn't `Write` the name of the PROCedure ?). Whenever you do an I/O operation, you must check if it is successfully done, otherwise the next I/O's operation can generate a RUN-TIME's ERROR.
I've successfully compiled this source code.
However I don't know what you want it does, because the program, as said by another user, is incomplete.

```
model small

BufSize EQU 60

.stack 100h
.data
    rez db "rez.txt", 0       ; NULL TERMINATOR WAS OMIT.
    Buf db BufSize dup (32)   ; CHARACTERS WITHOUT A PURPOSE (SPACES).
    ;handle  dw ?             ; NOT NEEDED.
    ;Letters db 0             ; NOT USED.
    brackets1 db " (letters$"
    brackets2 db ")$"
.code
start:
    MOV ax, @data
    MOV ds, ax

    MOV ah, 3Ch
    MOV cx, 0
    MOV dx, offset rez
    ; AH      -> 3CH, CREATE A FILE WITH HANDLE.
    ; CX      -> Attribute for file:
    ;            Bit0: read-only.
    ;            Bit1: hidden.
    ;            Bit2: system.
    ;            Bit3: volume-label.
    ;            Bit4: directory.
    ;            Bit5: archive.
    ;            Bit6: UNKNOWN.
    ;            Bit7: shareable.
    ; DS:DX   -> ASCIZ file-name (with optional drive and path).
    ; OUTPUT  -> FCarry=1:       ERROR, AX= error-code;
    ;            FCarry=0: SUCCESSFULL, AX= file-handle.
    INT 21h              ; Results file is created and opened.
    JB  openfailed       ; If error, exit.
    ;MOV handle, ax      ; Not needed.

    ;MOV cx, 5           ; 5 bytes ("Hello")
    ;ADD cx, 10          ; 10 bytes from "(letters " and ")"
    MOV bx, ax           ; Copy file-handle into BX's reg.
    CALL    Write

    MOV ah, 3Eh
    ;MOV bx, handle      ; BX's reg. already contains handle.
    ; AH      -> 3EH, CLOSE A FILE WITH HANDLE.
    ; BX      -> File-handle
    ; OUTPUT  -> FCarry=1:       ERROR, AX= error-code;
    ;            FCarry=0: SUCCESSFULL.
    INT 21h              ; Close file

openfailed:
    MOV ah, 4Ch
    MOV al, 0
    ; AH      -> 4CH, QUIT WITH EXIT CODE (EXIT).
    ; AL      -> EXIT CODE.
    INT 21h

Write:
    ; I suppose that you want to write the content of the buffer (Buf),
    ; followed by brackets1 and brackets2 strings.
    ; NOTE: Buf CONTAINS ONLY CHARACTERS WITHOUT A PURPOSE !
    ;PUSH    dx          ; Because DX's reg. is only used here, don't need to PUSH/POP it

    MOV ah, 40h
    MOV cx, BufSize      ; Size of Buf
    MOV dx, offset Buf
    ;  AH     -> 40H, WRITE TO FILE WITH HANDLE
    ;  BX     -> Handle
    ;  CX     -> Buffer's size
    ;  DS:DX  -> Buffer
    ; OUTPUT  -> FCarry=1:       ERROR, AX= error-code;
    ;            FCarry=0: SUCCESSFULL, AX= num. of byte written.
    INT 21h              ; Write to file
    JB  error            ; If error, return

    MOV ah, 40h
    MOV cx, 10           ; Size of brackets1's string
    MOV dx, offset brackets1
    ;  AH     -> 40H, WRITE TO FILE WITH HANDLE
    ;  BX     -> Handle
    ;  CX     -> Buffer's size
    ;  DS:DX  -> Buffer
    ; OUTPUT  -> FCarry=1:       ERROR, AX= error-code;
    ;            FCarry=0: SUCCESSFULL, AX= num. of byte written.
    INT 21h
    JB  error            ; If error, return

    MOV ah, 40h
    MOV cx, 2            ; Size of brackets2's string
    MOV dx, offset brackets2
    ;  AH     -> 40H, WRITE TO FILE WITH HANDLE
    ;  BX     -> Handle
    ;  CX     -> Buffer's size
    ;  DS:DX  -> Buffer
    ; OUTPUT  -> FCarry=1:       ERROR, AX= error-code;
    ;            FCarry=0: SUCCESSFULL, AX= num. of byte written.
    INT 21h
error:
    ;POP dx              ; Because DX's reg. is only used here, don't need to PUSH/POP it
    RET

END start
```

Comment: Thank you Man! All I needed is that I should declare my cx everytime i want to print, instead of adding them all and sending to procedure. I will add jumps if errors also. Thank you! My program has to input text from 2 files, then I have to insert previous symbols instead of spaces and count the amount of spaces in the text. Sorry for bothering with non-full program. I had to hurry and I couldn't translate all my code from national language to english.

Comment: You are welcome. If you do not need very large strings, for example, if you store every line of text in the headed-strings (Pascal-format) that they can contain up to 255 characters, you can write a unique routine you call when you need to save a data-block without every time having to set the `CX` register (+ other registers as `AH`) every time. The passed parameter is the string address in `DX` (the length of the string results from the first Byte in it, but you have to increase `DX` by 1 before the `INT 21H`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. You are awesome, dude! :)